# Invalid path error while cloning or pulling a branch into PhpStorm

Tags: git, gitlab, phpstorm

Using PhpStorm on a Windows machine and trying to do `git pull` or `git clone` from a remote repo and it returns the following:

```
error: invalid path 'Docs/AdminHelp/en/Inventory/Contract financials | Financial fields calculation (recalculate_fields).md'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
```

Other team members are working with the same repo, but on my end I keep getting this error. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: How does `git clone` or `git pull` behave in a git bash terminal? Just causing issues in phpstorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Docs/AdminHelp/en/Inventory/Contract financials | Financial fields calculation (recalculate_fields).md
                                               ^^^
```

A [pipe is not allowed in Windows file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/6309), so you would need to:

- double-check your colleagues are using the repository on Linux/Mac
- use a Linux-based VM (or WSL2 if your Windows is a Windows 10 recent enough)

In that Linux-based environment, you would be able to checkout the repository.

Or, you would request from your colleagues to `git mv`/rename that file with a more sensible name.